# elegir un reporte según el parámetro?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, sap, reporting

Consulta! como puedo elegir el tipo de reporte usando parámetros?
Ejemplo. Listado de facturas.
Opcion 1. Resumido.
Opcion 2. Detallado.

Estoy usando Crystal Report + SAP BO

Answer (score 0):

Puedes generar un enumerable, para asignarlos. Y después mandar un entero para ejecutar el que desees.

```
public enum reportes
{
    Resumido = 1;
    Detallado = 2;
}
```

Y estar validando con algún switch.

```
switc((int)reportes){
    case 1: //logica de Resumido   
    break; 
    case 2: //logica de Detallado 
    break;
}
```